# Slim - Having trouble nesting an element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I cannot figure this out. For some reason my code below is producing this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_do, expecting keyword_end
```

Code:

```
header.full-width-row  
  .columns.large-4
    .field-with-icon
      == fa_icon 'search'
      == search_field :user, :name, class: 'left', placeholder: "search"
  .columns.large-8
    .button-bar
      ul.button-group
        li.tiny.button.filterable-tab.active data={ tabvalue: '*'} =("All #{@users.count}")
        - User.statuses.each do |tab_value|
          li
            a.tiny.button.filterable-tab data=({tabvalue: tab_value[0].to_s}) =(tab_value[0].to_s.capitalize)
              label test
```

The error is caused by the label on the last line. When it is removed the page loads perfectly. I am wondering why I cannot nest this label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already defined `a.tiny.button.filterable-tab` content in the line before the label, when you added `=(tab_value[0].to_s.capitalize)` at the end.

Change the last two lines

```
a.tiny.button.filterable-tab data=({tabvalue: tab_value[0].to_s}) =(tab_value[0].to_s.capitalize)
  label test
```

to

```
a.tiny.button.filterable-tab data=({tabvalue: tab_value[0].to_s})
  = tab_value[0].to_s.capitalize
  label test
```